# Search database for a string

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find a value that is in a very large database with hundreds of tables. I'm not sure which table it is in or which field it is in. Is there a way to do the following in MySQL somehow (whether directly via a query or some other way):

```
-- in pseudocode
SELECT tablename, * FROM <ALL_TABLES> WHERE <ANY_VALUE> = "LOGO_and_Wordmark"
```

Comment: Would [one of these solutions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34856/how-to-search-whole-mysql-database-for-a-particular-string) work? There are a few ways to accomplish the goal, all of which are somewhat involved …

Comment: @matigo thanks for sharing that. All the methods seem pretty involved!

Comment: you can dump in csv and use hive to search your requirement.